# i wan to select the text inside input field by clicking on a button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code to select the text inside input field but it does not work.

```js
const editItem = () => {
    let inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
    console.log(inputBox);
    inputBox.focus();
    inputBox.select();
  };
```

when someone clicks this button the above code is supposed the run and select the text inside input field but it doesnt

```
        <button type='button' className="edit-btn" onClick = {()=>editItem()}>
```

Edit:this is my input box

```
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="e.g. eggs"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        id="input-box"  
      />
```

Comment: We can't see an `input-box` element in your example, also, why would you query the DOM when you using React? Use React API instead.

Comment: are you sure "input-box" is id and not class? console log `let inputBox` and tell us what you got

Comment: Right I'm guessing you have the id wrong.
Also, shouldn't you just be using a useRef?

Comment: @DennisVash I have added the input box , actually I don't know how to use react API , can you please explain

Comment: @Alex can you please tell how do i use useRef to get my results, I am new in React

Comment: @Roy.B i am getting this  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. eggs" id="input-box" value="eggs">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying the DOM is an anti-pattern in React (unless you really know what you doing), instead use dedicated API for it, like [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const editItem = () => {
    inputRef.current.select();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        defaultValue="Eggs"
        placeholder="e.g. eggs"
      />
      <button type="button" className="edit-btn" onClick={editItem}>
        Focus
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nifty-buck-si9zo]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {

    function editItem() {
        document.getElementById("input-box").select();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="input-box"/>
            <button type='button' onClick={editItem}>button</button>
        </div>
     )
}
```

Comment: Although this may work, it's not considered the "React way" and using a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) protects against edge cases where a react re-render changes the element unexpectedly.